# How do I print an array in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to Rails and I am using Ruby version 1.9.3 and Rails version 3.0.0.

I want to print an array in Rails. How do I do that?

For example, we have to use `print_r` to print an array in PHP:

```
<?php

$a = array ('a' => 'apple', 'b' => 'banana', 'c' => array ('x', 'y', 'z'));
print_r ($a);

?>
```

Output:

```
<pre>
Array
(
    [a] => apple
    [b] => banana
    [c] => Array
        (
            [0] => x
            [1] => y
            [2] => z
        )
)
</pre>
```

How do I print an array in Rails?

Comment: `<%= debug array %>` or `<%= array.inspect %>`

Answer (score 11):

You can use `inspect` like:

```
@a = ['a', 'b']
p @a #['a', 'b']
```

Or:

```
p @a.inspect #"[\"a\", \"b\"]"
```

Comment: We can use <%= @a.inspect %> if we need to render it to a html page.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`awesome_print`](https://github.com/michaeldv/awesome_print) gem.

```
require 'awesome_print'

hash = {:a=>1,:b=>2,:c => [1,2,3]}

ap hash
```

output:

```
{
    :a => 1,
    :b => 2,
    :c => [
        [0] 1,
        [1] 2,
        [2] 3
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got a couple of options here. I'm assuming you're doing this in an ERB template.

This will convert the array to YAML and print it out surrounded in `<pre>` tags

```
<%= debug [1,2,3,4] %>
```

And this will print it out formatted in a readable Ruby syntax:

```
<pre><%= [1,2,3,4].inspect %></pre>
```

Check out "[Debugging Rails Applications](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html)" for more info.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to use the array for.

To blindly output an array in a view, which *has to be in a view*, you should use `debug` and `inspect` like this:

```
<%= @array.inspect() %>

<%= debug @array %>
```

However, if you want to iterate through an array, or do things like `explode()`, you'll be better suited using the Ruby array functions.